# Insert sales cloud record upon submit in smart capture form cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

is there any way to insert a salesforce record upon clicking of submit in smart capture form for cloud pages.

This are the following approach that I'm thinking of but I'm not sure if they're possible.

1.) I have a validation for my smart capture form field via , Is it possible to add SSJS inside this script so if all is valid I can just do a SSJS to insert salesforce record?

2.) Pass a primary key to the thank you cloud page. So upon clicking of submit it will be redirected to a thank you page from there I can use the primary key to get values from to the dataextension and insert in salescloud with ampscript

Any recommendation would be swell.

Comment: See if this helps: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/ - All you will need to do is add a function to upsert submitted data into a Data Extension: https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add SSJS into validation script, as it is executed in the front-end only. I would very much recommend moving away from Smart Capture and build a custom solution, which will use Ampscript function of [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) before upserting the form data to a data extension. This way you ensure you can store the field values with a reference to e.g. Contact ID from Sales Cloud, which is returned by CreateSalesforceObject function.

All fields submitted in the form are easily referenced using [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) function. Ensuring CreateSalesforceObject is called before you upsert data to a Data Extension will also help with deduplication, as if a Contact with the provided email address already exists, the ID of this Contact is returned, instead of creating a new record.

You can find a good example of code behind such approach on [zuzannamj's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/) site: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/